# Laravel on Windows Server: main(): Failed opening required ... (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Tags: php, laravel, iis, pear, windows-server

I am using Laravel 5.2 on Windows Server (IIS), and in my controller (`app\Http\Controllers\Test\NewsletterController.php`) I need to require a file:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../Mailwizz/setup.php';
```

(this file is stored in `app\Mailwizz\setup.php`).

But I am getting the following error:

```
main(): Failed opening required 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.com\app\Http\Controllers\Test
../../../Mailwizz/setup.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

Maybe it has something to do with `include_path` in **php.ini**, but I'm not sure how to setup this on Windows Server... here is my current **php.ini**:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
```

Do you know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../Mailwizz/setup.php';
```

with

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../Mailwizz/setup.php';
```

I think that you error is caused by missing slash.